# Quanto menos consulta melhor, certo?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

É possível variar a escrita dos resultados, como exemplo segue abaixo onde pretendo utilizar.

```
<table width="1000" align="center">
    <tr> 
      <td>&nbsp;NOTICIAS</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <tr> 
      <td width="350"> <?php
                                $sql = "SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE categoria='noticias' ORDER BY idnoticia DESC LIMIT 1";
                                $stmt = DB::prepare($sql);
                                $stmt->execute();
                                $exibe = $stmt->fetchAll();
                                foreach ($exibe as $u) { 
                                echo "<div style='float:left;width:99%;margin-right:10px;'><a  style='color:#000;text-decoration:none;' href='{$u->categoria}.php?idnoticia={$u->idnoticia}'>";
                                echo "<div class='thumbnail'> <img src='img/{$u->idnoticia}/{$u->imagem}' class='img-responsive'>";
                                echo "<div class='limit'>{$u->titulo}";
                                echo "</div></div></a></div>";

                                ?></td>
      <td width="650"><?php
                                $sql = "SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE categoria='noticias' ORDER BY idnoticia DESC LIMIT 6 OFFSET 1";
                                $stmt = DB::prepare($sql);
                                $stmt->execute();
                                $exibe = $stmt->fetchAll();
                                foreach ($exibe as $u) { 
                                echo "<div style='float:left;width:99%;margin-right:10px;'><a  style='color:#000;text-decoration:none;' href='{$u->categoria}.php?idnoticia={$u->idnoticia}'>";
                                echo "<div class='thumbnail'> <img src='img/{$u->idnoticia}/{$u->imagem}' class='img-responsive'>";
                                echo "<div class='limit'>{$u->titulo}";
                                echo "</div></div></a></div>";

                                ?></td>
  </table>
```

Posso aproveitar o mesmo `select` usado no primeiro `<td>` para continuar o resultado apos o 2° `<td>`? Como escrever o 1º resultado, "pausar" e reescrever o restante de outra maneira?

Comment: Olha não posso lhe dizer se isto é real, mas até aonde sei não é o acesso de um único usuário que irá fazer a diferença, mas quando estamos em um servidor e vários usuários acessam ao mesmo tempo pode haver um aumento do uso da maquina servidor, ou seja, pela lógica que proponho aqui, quanto mais conexões, menos "performance", quanto menos conexões "melhor", corrija-me se eu estiver enganado.

Comment: Pois então, tambem não creio que é o acesso de um único usuário que irá fazer a diferença, porem penso exatamente nesse caso de muitos acessos simultaneos, até quanto pode ser prejudicial 2 consultas, sendo que no caso poderia ser ( acho ) que usada so uma?

Comment: Ao meu ver então a questão seria criar um estrutura de cache das páginas quando possível (além de fazer uma query só) e em questão de optimizar o php, você poderia usar `fetch` ao invés de `fetchAll` e não usar buffers nas queries, exemplo com pdo `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, false);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sim, é possível. Estou considerando que o código está correto (mas acho que ele tem erros):

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE categoria='noticias' ORDER BY idnoticia DESC LIMIT 6";
$stmt = DB::prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$exibe = $stmt->fetchAll();
?>
<table width="1000" align="center">
    <tr> 
      <td>&nbsp;NOTICIAS</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td width="350">
          <?php
          echo "<div style='float:left;width:99%;margin-right:10px;'><a  style='color:#000;text-decoration:none;' href='{$exibe[0]->categoria}.php?idnoticia={$exibe[0]->idnoticia}'>";
          echo "<div class='thumbnail'> <img src='img/{$exibe[0]->idnoticia}/{$exibe[0]->imagem}' class='img-responsive'>";
          echo "<div class='limit'>{$exibe[0]->titulo}";
          echo "</div></div></a></div>";
          ?>
      </td>
      <td width="650">
          <?php
          $tamanho = count($exibe);
          for ($i = 1; $i < $tamanho; $i++) { 
              echo "<div style='float:left;width:99%;margin-right:10px;'><a  style='color:#000;text-decoration:none;' href='{$exibe[$i]->categoria}.php?idnoticia={$exibe[$i]->idnoticia}'>";
              echo "<div class='thumbnail'> <img src='img/{$exibe[$i]->idnoticia}/{$exibe[$i]->imagem}' class='img-responsive'>";
              echo "<div class='limit'>{$exibe[$i]->titulo}";
              echo "</div></div></a></div>";
          }
          ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Database/LessQuert.php).

Você lê todos os 6 itens que você deseja de uma vez só, aí usa o primeiro separado dos 5 seguintes. Ao invés de duas viagens para buscar a informação no banco de dados, você faz apenas uma e resolve a separação dentro do PHP.

Comment: era realmente mesmo essa a intenção, vou testar aqui, creio eu que fazendo apenas 1 consulta a resposta do site devera ficar mais rapida

Comment: De fato, sua pergunta original está no caminho certo, sempre deve economizar viagens ao banco de dados.

Comment: @ArsomNolasco você tem 27 perguntas e apenas 8 votos dados. Você sabe que você pode votar também? E que isto é importante? Pode votar inclusive em outras coisas no site? http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159/101 Tem até um ranking de quem vota mais http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all Veja o [tour] Seria legal revisar as perguntas que fez se tem respostas que merecem seu voto. Ou mesmo ver se tem perguntas no site que merecem seu voto, além de respostas nelas que lhe ajudaram aprender algo novo ou pode ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: fiz da maneira que vc sugeriu e ok tudo certo porem tem algo que esta gerando a mais veja anexo a imagem http://prntscr.com/6piust , sera alguma coisa no count?

Comment: Não consigo perceber exatamente o que está diferente. A notícia maior é a primeira listada e as outras são as demais? Você está mostrando 1 + 8, você mudou isto mesmo? Aí teria uma 10a. notícia que não deveria estar sendo mostrada mas não deveria? Este é o problema? Se for isto, você já mudou o código original, não sei se essa modificação foi feita corretamente. Se não é isto, o seu código parece fazer algo muito diferente do que está sendo mostrado. Não é fácil falar algo sem ver o código real.

Comment: mudei sim 1+8 , no caso a 10ª nao era pra ser mostrada, me parece estar sendo contada 1 a mais  veja o print do meu codigo modificado http://prntscr.com/6pj1j2

Comment: Eu comi bola, o operador de comparação está errado mesmo, era para usar, `<` e não `<=`.

Comment: realmente era isso, <= ele conta o primeiro tambem, nem me atentei. agora esta bunito, depois sinalizo os meus votos so daki 5 horas denovo, segui seu conselho e revisei as minhas perguntas era o minimo

Answer (score 5):

Cada caso é um caso, mas no teu caso, sim, quanto menos consultas melhor! Até porque essencialmente estás a repetir a mesma consulta.

Geralmente em PHP, a tendência é dividir o tratamento da informação em 3 camadas distintas, de forma a facilitar a leitura e futura manutenção. Para o teu caso, falamos essencialmente em:

1. [*Data layer*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_layer) - Interação com base de dados
2. [*Business layer*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_logic) - Tratamento da informação
3. *Interface layer* - O HTML

Aplicando este conceito, já estamos a responder à tua pergunta porque se vamos tratar a informação antes de a utilizar, uma consulta serve para trazer todas as "noticias" e na fase de tratamento separamos a primeira das restantes:

1. Interagir com base de dados

   ```
   /* Data layer
    * Consultar base de dados para recolher informação
    */
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE categoria='noticias' ORDER BY idnoticia DESC LIMIT 7";
   $stmt = DB::prepare($sql);
   $stmt->execute();
   $exibe = $stmt->fetchAll();
   ```
2. Trabalhar e preparar a informação

   ```
   /* Business layer
    * Trabalhar os dados preparando o HTML a inserir na interface
    */
   $primeiraNoticia = $outrasNoticias = '';
   $contador = 0;

   foreach ($exibe as $u) {

       $noticia = '
       <div class="noticiasWrapper">
         <a href="'.$u->categoria.'.php?idnoticia='.$u->idnoticia.'">
           <div class="thumbnail">
             <img src="img/'.$u->idnoticia.'/'.$u->imagem.'" class="img-responsive">
             <div class="limit">'.$u->titulo.'</div>
           </div>
         </a>
       </div>';

       if ($contador>0) {
         $outrasNoticias .= $noticia;
       } else {
         $primeiraNoticia .= $noticia;
       }

       $contador++;
   }
   ```
3. Apresentar a informação

   ```html
   <!-- Interface layer
        Aplicar a informação no nosso layout e enviar a mesma para o navegador
    -->
   <style type="text/css">
       /* CSS deve ficar em ficheiro .CSS mas caso no documento,
          desta forma não andamos a duplicar a informação para o navegador */
       .noticiaWrapper{
         float:left;width:99%;margin-right:10px;
       }
       .noticiaWrapper > a{
         color:#000;text-decoration:none;
       }
   </style>

   <table width="1000" align="center">
       <tr>
           <td>NOTICIAS</td>
           <td> </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td width="350"><?php echo $primeiraNoticia; ?></td>
           <td width="650"><?php echo $outrasNoticias; ?></td>
       </tr>
   </table>
   ```

---

**Notas:** Podes ter tudo no mesmo ficheiro `.PHP` pela ordem em cima apresentada, ou mais tarde vir a separar em múltiplos ficheiros de forma ágil dado já teres as diversas camadas devidamente separadas.